# stroke order of 點

Tags: stroke-order, strokes

On some resources, the sixth and seventh stroke is not the same.

For instance :

https://www.archchinese.com/chinese_english_dictionary.html?find=%E9%BB%9E

http://www.chinesehideout.com/tools/strokeorder.php?c=%E9%BB%9E

A friend sent me other characters with the same thing :

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:%E9%BB%91#/media/File:%E9%BB%91-bw.png

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/%E9%BB%92-jbw.png

Here is an article which explains that the vertical one must be the first :

https://www.chinlingo.com/articles/601078/

My questions are :

1. What is the correct stroke order ?
2. When I'm in doubt because of contradictions, where can I find a correct specification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the first 8 stroke consist of 四(four) and 土(soil). So first 5 strokes just follow 四. Next 3 strokes follows 土. So the vertical stroke come after the first horizontal stroke. Rule of thumb is horizontal before vertical.

There is an Android app about Chinese Stroke order. You may want to check it out:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ansami.hkchinesechar